# Update/Reset android firmware by SD Card. Verizon Samsung S4

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, recovery-mode, verizon

I have a Verizon Samsung Galaxy S4 that was rooted on the 4.3 build with the saferoot method (I think, it's been awhile). I had since installed Xposed framework and installer, etc.  I unrooted with the supersu unroot method. Now I can't connect my phone via USB in either Ubuntu or Windows 7 (it shows unknown device).  Another S4 shows up and installs drivers just fine on my computer, and my phone isn't recognized by other computers running windows. Basically, no matter what I've done with ADB and Windows drivers, my phone will not talk with my PC and I cannot connect to Odin. I've factory reset my phone, and I just want to be able to communicate via USB.

I'm looking at taking some of the firmware I've found on XDA-forums and installing that through the stock recovery with the SD card. `SCH-I545_VZW_1_20131023084910_v4vth34m5z_fac.zip` is the package I have.

My question: is this okay to just push this `.zip` via stock recovery?  Is there anything else I need to do, like install other packages, etc?

EDIT: After factory resetting both in the android OS AND in stock recovery, trying to take the OTA fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the actual USB port on the phone. Not only is it actually communicating, but it's charging a lot faster. The part is fairly easy to change and fairly cheap as well.